# App working fine on emulator but not working on android device

Tags: android, android-emulator, client-server, wifi

I am developing a simple client server login application. The application works fine on emulator but when i run the application from phone it doesn't work. I have also added the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`  I am connecting my android phone via wifi and also tested the connectivity with the Terminal Emulator app by pinging my server.

```
URL = "http://192.168.1.2:8084/AndroidServlet/AndroidServlet?name="+name+"&pass="+pass;
```

This the URL which i am using to connect to the server and 192.168.1.2 is the IP address of my machine.

```
public class SimServletActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
Button button;
String name,pass;
EditText us_id,us_password;
public String URL = "http://192.168.1.1:8084/AndroidServlet/AndroidServlet?name="+name+"&pass="+pass;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    findViewsById();
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void findViewsById() {
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    us_id=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginid);
    us_password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
}
public void getDetails(){
     name=us_id.getText().toString();
     pass=us_password.getText().toString();
     URL = "http://192.168.1.1:8084/AndroidServlet/AndroidServlet?name="+name+"&pass="+pass;
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    getDetails();
    GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
    task.execute(new String[] { URL });
}

private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String output = null;
        for (String url : urls) {
            output = getOutputFromUrl(url);
        }
        return output;
    }

    private String getOutputFromUrl(String url) {
        String output = null;
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            output = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return output;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String output) {

        if(output.equals("true"))
        {
            Intent i=new Intent(SimServletActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(SimServletActivity.this, "Enter correct Details",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }
}
```

}

Any Help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

LogCat details are `E/AndroidRuntime(26414): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(26414): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(26414):    at com.eg.simpleservlet.SimServletActivity$GetXMLTask.onPostExecute(SimServletActivity.java:88)
E/AndroidRuntime(26414):    at com.eg.simpleservlet.SimServletActivity$GetXMLTask.onPostExecute(SimServletActivity.java:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(26414):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
E/AndroidRuntime(26414):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
E/AndroidRuntime(26414):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
E/AndroidRuntime(26414):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(26414):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime(26414):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
E/AndroidRuntime(26414):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(26414):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(26414):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
E/AndroidRuntime(26414):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
E/AndroidRuntime(26414):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Comment: "but not working on android device" - What exactly is wrong? Maybe stack trace from log give us chance to point you in right direction.

Comment: @Shubhanshu is that link from local server.

Comment: ya it is a link to my local server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Website is returning a null String,

```
if(output.equals("true"))
```

would fail like you described. You could use

```
if ((output!=null) && output.equals("true"))
```

instead.

Comment: personally, I prefer to make it more explicit in this case.

Comment: It doesn't make it more explicit, it just makes it more complex.

Comment: @DigCamara thanks for the help but when i used your code the app runs fine. But my problem is not solved i am getting null value from the server when i checked it with the help of logcat.

Comment: Seems like the connectivity with your server isn't right when you're working from your phone. Have you tried entering your URL in a browser to see if it works?